# How to do set the uri by calling the ERC1155 upgradeable initialize function from a proxy

Tags: proxy-contracts

```
const { ethers, upgrades } = require("hardhat");

async function main() {
const ERC1155 = await ethers.getContractFactory("ERC1155");
const uri = "ipfs://QmYcYVfbaBcfbkZ9RL38xMEUsa462zGXR5hEPvs4VGGesC/{id}.json";
const proxy = await upgrades.deployProxy(ERC1155, uri, { initializer: '__ERC1155_init' });
await proxy.deployed();

console.log(proxy.address);
}

main();
```

When running this script, I get the error:

TypeError: Cannot create property 'kind' on string 'ipfs://QmYcYVfbaBcfbkZ9RL38xMEUsa462zGXR5hEPvs4VGGesC/{id}.json'

I find that the script runs and uploads fine if I instead replace "uri" with "String" in the 4th line of the code but the initializer does not get called (obviously this would set the uri in the ERC1155 contract to nothing)

Here is the function from the ERC1155Upgradeable contract:

```
function __ERC1155_init(string memory uri_) internal onlyInitializing {
    __ERC1155_init_unchained(uri_);
}

function __ERC1155_init_unchained(string memory uri_) internal onlyInitializing {
    _setURI(uri_);
}
```

If anyone has a solution to this, I would be happy to know, thank you.

Edit:

I realized using:

```
function __init(string memory uri_) public initializer {
    __ERC1155_init(uri_);
    __Ownable_init();
}
```

Vs:

```
function __init(string memory uri_) public onlyInitializing {
    __ERC1155_init(uri_);
    __Ownable_init();
}
```

Where the modifier is switched from "onlyInitializing" to "initializer" allowed me to call the initializer. When testing on remix, I got the error: "Initializable: contract is not initializing". when using onlyInitializing.

Why does the ERC1155Upgradeable use onlyInitializing vs initializer?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the way you are calling uri within the deployProxy Hardhat API.

The message makes it look like you are trying to set the Proxy type (default is transparent) as either UUPS or Transparent with the argument.

I think you need [uri] as args to pass to initializer.

```
const proxy = await upgrades.deployProxy(ERC1155, [uri], { initializer: '__ERC1155_init' });
```

https://docs.openzeppelin.com/upgrades-plugins/1.x/api-hardhat-upgrades#common-options